# dump files downloaded by google Colab in temporary location to google drive

Tags: python, url, google-colaboratory

I have a json file with over 16k urls of images, which I parse using a python script and use `urllib.request.urlretrieve` in it to retrieve images. I uploaded the json file to google drive and run the python script in google Colab.

Though the files were downloaded (I checked this using a print line in the try block of urlretrieve) and it took substantial time to download them, I am unable to see where it has stored these files. When I had run the same script on my local machine, it stored the files in the current folder.

As an answer to this question suggests, the files may be downloaded to some temporary location, say, on some cloud. Is there a way to dump these temporary files to google drive?

(*Note I had mounted the drive in the colab notebook, still the files don't appear to be stored in google drive)

Answer (score 1):

Colab stores files in some temp location which is new every time you run the notebook. If you want your data to persist across sessions you need to store it in GDrive. For that you need to map some GDrive folder in your notebook and use it as path. Also, you need to give the Colab permissions to access your GDrive

Comment: I had written from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive') to mount the drive at the start of the script. Shouldn't that store the files in gdrive?

Comment: Afair, `drive.mount('/content/gdrive')` returns some value which you then use as base dir for all the writes/reads

Answer (score 1):

After mounting GDrive you need to move files from the Colab to GDrive using command:

```
!mv /content/filename /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/
```

Comment: After mounting GDrive, copy the paths of both your temp folder and GDrive folder using copy path command using right-click dropdown and use the !mv command as suggested.